# Python dictionary attack only solves the last hash

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

I'm trying to build a dictionary attack script (for education purposes) using Python and it only ever solves the last SHA-256 hash in my file.

The logic is as follows:

- Read a file containing words
- Store the hashed value of the word along with the word as a key-value pair in a dictionary
- Scan the lines of a text file containing SHA-256 hashes (1 hashed value per line)
- Iterate over the items in the dictionary and print the key if a value matches the hash

It works perfectly for the very last item in my file, but says a match was not found for all my others.

My hash file looks like:

```
9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08
5E884898DA28047151D0E56F8DC6292773603D0D6AABBDD62A11EF721D1542D8
```

Containing the hashed values for "test" and "password".

My word file contains over 70,000 words and I've made sure both words are in the file, and when I debug, they both have values in the dictionary if I call the expression.

Here's where I iterate over the hashes in my file:

```
with open(hashFile) as f:
    for c in f:
        findMatch(str(c).lower(),wordMap)
```

And the function I wrote to compare a hashed value to every value in the dictionary:

```
def findMatch(hv,m):
    #k is the key, m is the dictionary
    for k in m:
        if(m[k].lower() == hv):
            print("Match was found: " + k )
            return
    print("Match was not found, searched through " + str(len(wordMap)) + " words")
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `findMatch(str(c).lower(),wordMap)`, there is no need to call `str()` (because `c` is already a string), but there **is** a need to strip off the trailing newline character: `findMatch(c.strip().lower(),wordMap)`. Otherwise, it is included in the hash value calculation. Apparently the last line of your file does not have the trailing newline, that's why it is correctly recognized.